# How to calculate count of records by 2 columns

Tags: mysql

In `MySQL` I have a table.

**Example:**

```
id name type
1 Thomas 2
2 Thomas 2
3 Thomas 1
4   Paul 3
5   Paul 4
6   Paul 4
```

I need calculate same records by 2 columns.
Result for this example should be:

```
name   type   countOfRecords
Thomas 2       2
Thomas 1       1
Paul   3       1
Paul   4       2
```

Could you help me with this request?

Comment: You should give examples of what you have tried so far and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want records in your result set for each name and type `<name,type>` pair 
you need to group by `name` and `type`.

```
SELECT 
name,
type,
COUNT(*) countOfRecords
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name,type;
```

**Note:**

`Group BY <some column>` would generate a result set where **number of rows = number of distinct / different / unique `<some column>`**.

Same holds for multiple columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This may be right solution:

```
SELECT  name, type, COUNT(*) as countOfRecords
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name,type;
```